# How is the USD price on Binance calculated since there is no USD involved in the whole exchange?

Tags: exchange-rate

I'm talking about this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2RzI.png
How is it calculated?

Comment: Maybe it uses composite score of other exchanges specially if it never trades a crypto to dollar or vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

There are USDT markets in binance. If you are unaware, USDT is backed by USD and binance can use their own market's USDT value.